# Cannot open ADO Recordset more than once

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that is passed a SQL string, queries a SQL server, and return the results via a an array.  This function works perfectly the first time, but I try to call it again it get:

> Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Oddly enough this error occures right after the Open statement.  I've Googled about everything I can think of, with no good results.

```
Public Function SQL_Query(SQLCommand As String) As Variant
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim SQLrs As New ADODB.Recordset

    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=10.XXX.XXXX.XXX;DataBase=Database1;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
    cn.Open
    SQLrs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    Call SQLrs.Open(SQLCommand, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic)

    SQLrs.MoveFirst

    SQL_Query = RecordSet2Array(SQLrs.GetRows)

    SQLrs.Close
    Set SQLrs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've finally tracked this to SQL query I was using in my second call to the function.  It creates a temp table and returns records from that temp table.  This is apparently and [known issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/295743).  However it's easily corrected by `SET NOCOUNT ON`.  So I've updated my code to the following and everything is working fine now.

```
Public Function SQL_Query(SQLCommand As String) As Variant
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim SQLrs As New ADODB.Recordset

    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=10.XXX.XXXX.XXX;DataBase=Database1;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
    cn.Open
    cn.Execute "SET NOCOUNT ON"
    SQLrs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    Call SQLrs.Open(SQLCommand, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic)

    SQLrs.MoveFirst

    SQL_Query = RecordSet2Array(SQLrs.GetRows)

    SQLrs.Close
    Set SQLrs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading right - you're opening the SQL connection again, but not the recordset (SQLrs). You have to create a new instance each time on open and close both when done, or you tend to get these issues on re-running.

Comment: This is a function that is called more than once.  The first time it is called results are returned.  The second time and every time after that the SQLrs gives the "object is closed error".  So, I should be instantiating a new recordset object every time the function is called.  Therefore, I would think that I'm opening an new recordset every time.  However, this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I've not used ADO in a function in this way, so it may be that I am wrong - but I did have a similar issue when calling a subroutine that was solved by closing and opening the recordsets between uses.

Comment: Am I not closing the recordset at the end of the function, in the code above?  `SQLrs.Close` Then opening it again on the next call `Call SQLrs.Open(...)`?

Comment: I think the issue you are getting is because you are trying to set the cursorlocation before opening the connection. I tend not to set anything to doing with the recordset before opening. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I've not experienced it personally, but I've been told that `Dim x as NEW y` can lead to issues.

Try this change to see if it helps:

```
Public Function SQL_Query(SQLCommand As String) As Variant
    'changes here vvvvvvvv
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim SQLrs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set SQLrs = New ADODB.Recordset
    'to here ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=10.XXX.XXXX.XXX;DataBase=Database1;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
    cn.Open
    SQLrs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    Call SQLrs.Open(SQLCommand, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic)

    SQLrs.MoveFirst

    SQL_Query = RecordSet2Array(SQLrs.GetRows)

    SQLrs.Close
    Set SQLrs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing

End Function
```